# Address creation in blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain, accounts

Is moment of account creation stored in blockchain?
Or only first income or outcome transaction time can estimate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Account creation can be done completely offline and there is no way to know. The only thing you can tell is the first time it is referenced on-chain, e.g. the first transaction (or mining reward) to it.